# CodedUI : The Browser gets closed as finish testing without keeping for testing further steps

Tags: c#, testing, browser, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I'm working on a CodedUI project to check on a Web Solution.

There, when Im testing for launching the site (as in launching the web URL), I am facing an issue with closing the browser as it finish testing, where it wont allow to use the same browser instance  for further testing, Unless if I keep open a instance of a browser (IE) prior manually before running the test.

Can anyone please assist me with this, where I was unable to find a suitable solution. I even went through articles in MSDN where I posted regarding this issue as a comment which I'm facing, since I tried various ways of Code Snippets so far.

(MSDN : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/11/08/using-same-applicationundertest-browserwindow-across-multiple-tests.aspx)

My written code is provided below.

```
---
-- common.cs  
[TestMethod]
    public void LoadLocalHost()
    {
      this.UIMap.LoadLocalHost();
    } 
---
-- UIMap.Designer.cs
public void LoadLocalHost()
    { 
      this.UIMsnInternetExplorerWindow.LaunchUrl(new System.Uri("http://localhost:5500/"));
      Console.WriteLine(UIMsnInternetExplorerWindow.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup);
      UIMsnInternetExplorerWindow.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = false;
    }
```

Highly appreciate an assistance from some one who can.

Answer (score 0):

If you launch the browser in a class Initialize method rather than a test initialize method, and don't close it in your test or in a test cleanup, it should remain open for the duration of your tests, provided they are all executed within the same test class.

```
[ClassInitialize]
public void classInitialize()
{
    // Do some stuff, including launch the browser
    // This is executed once per class.
}

[TestInitialize]
public void testInitialize()
{
    // This is where you'd get the test back to a specific 
    // state, like bring your browser back to a home page or something.
    // It would be executed at the beginning of each test.
}

....

[TestMethod]
public void myFirstTest()
{
    // Do some more stuff specific to your test.
}

[TestMethod]
public void mySecondTest()
{
    // Do things after the last test.
}
....

[ClassCleanup]
public void classCleanup()
{
    // Finalize everything and close the browser.
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ryan,
I tried in your way by adding the 'this.UIMap.LoadLocalHost();' into the [ClassInitialize]. And it didn't launch the IE at all. I tried it by even an Ordered Test, which didn't work either. Will you be able to kindly assist me further?

Comment: If there are tests in multiple classes then you could try using the `[AssemblyInitialize]` and `[AssemblyCleanup]` methods.